# Receive realtime data from phone

Tags: linux, windows-7, server, virtual-machine

I am using an android app that streams real-time accelerometer data to the specified ip address of a server. I have written a "server" in C running on Linux which is running in VMware.

I am connected to the hotspot created by the Windows7(Host machine) running the VMware Workstation.

So my question is how do I connect the virtual-machine to same network as the hotspot so that I can get the phone and the "server" program on the same network and stream data to the server program?

Comment: Can you ping the host machine from the device?  Can you hit the service in the VM from the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

I use VirtualBox, but I'm guessing the settings are very similar in VMWare Workstation.

You probably need to do one or both of these things:

1) Port Forwarding.  If your app is hitting port 80 (or whatever port), you'll need to tell VMWare that any hits coming in to the host machine on that port get forwarded to the VM.  Of course, your VM will have to be listening on that port.  I'd suggest using a high port number (over 1024) to minimize conflicts, and avoid annoying root/admin issues using a low port number.

2) Hopefully that gets you there.  If not, you may need to change the virtual adapter settings on the VM.  NAT mode is a good first try.  If not, there are other modes (bridged, internal, host-only) you can tinker with.  (Not sure if VMWare uses different names)

That's probably all you need for the topology you describe -- Android device connected directly to the same subnet as the host machine.  If not, perhaps your hotspot routes all client traffic to the gateway (i.e. out to the Internet), without allowing direct access to localhost.  If so, maybe there are settings for that. If not, ngrok is your new best friend.

It is SUPER easy and allows you to tunnel traffic from anywhere on the Internet to a specific service running on your machine.  This would sidestep some of the issues above.

If you want to take your Android device to another network (e.g. cell network), then ngrok is absolutely the way to go, particularly for development and prototyping.  This lets you avoid issues with DNS, routing, firewalls, etc.